# Weak formulation and application of Lax-Milgram

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method, elliptic-equations

I am working with the following PDE:

---

\begin{align*}
-\nabla  \cdot (a(x) \nabla u) + b(x) u = f(x) &, \hspace{.5cm} x = (x_1,x_2) \in \Omega, \\
u = 0&, \hspace{.5cm} x \in \partial \Omega_1 \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} + u = 2&, \hspace{.5cm} x \in \partial \Omega_2, 
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*} 
&\Omega = \left\{ x \vert x_1 > 0, x_2 > 0, x_1 + x_2 < 1 \right\} , \\
&\partial \Omega_1 = \left\{x \vert x_1 = 0, 0 \leq x \leq 1 \right\} \cup \left\{ x \vert x_2 = 0, 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \right\} \\
&\partial \Omega_2 = \left\{x \vert x_1 > 0, x_2 > 0,  x_1+x_2 = 1 \right\} \\
&0 < a \leq a(x) \leq A, \text{ } 0 < b \leq b(x) \leq B  
\end{align*}

---

Here's what I have so far:

Let $H = \left\{  v \in H^1(\Omega) \vert v = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega_1 \right\}$. Then multiplying the PDE by $v$ and integrating by parts, we have \begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} fvdx &= - \int_{\partial \Omega} a(x) v \nabla u \cdot \nu ds + \int_{\Omega} (a(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + b(x)uv )dx \\
&= - \int_{\partial \Omega_2} a(x) v \nabla u \cdot \nu ds + \int_{\Omega} (a(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + b(x)uv )dx \\
&= - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{\partial \Omega_2} a(x) v (2-u) ds + \int_{\Omega} (a(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + b(x)uv )dx \\
\end{align*}
Let \begin{align*}
B(u,v) &= \int_{\Omega} (a(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + b(x)uv) dx + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{\partial \Omega_2} a(x) u v \text{ } ds\\
F(v) &= \int_{\Omega} fv \text{ } dx + \sqrt{2} \int_{\partial \Omega_2} a(x)v \text{ }  ds
\end{align*} 
Then the weak variational form of the problem would be

> Find $u \in H$ such that $B(u,v) = F(v)$ for all $v \in H$.

I'm fairly confident the weak variational formulation is correct, but I'm having trouble applying Lax-Milgram, particularly with how I apply the trace theorem. When I try to prove that $F$ is bounded, I obtain 
\begin{align*} 
\left| F(v) \right| &\leq \int_\Omega \left| f  v \right|dx + \sqrt{2} \int_{\partial \Omega_2} \left| a(x) v \right|ds \\
&\leq \| f \|_{L^2(\Omega)}\| v \|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \sqrt{2} \| a(x) \|_{L^2(\partial \Omega_2)} \| v \|_{L^2(\Omega_2)} \\
&\leq \| f \|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|  v \|_H + 2^{\frac{3}{4}}A \| v \|_{\partial \Omega_2 }.
\end{align*}
I know that the trace theorem must be used to complete the proof, but I don't really understand the details, particular when we are only dealing with a subset of the boundary. If anyone could let me know how to proceed from here, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: You can change the integral $\int_{\partial \Omega_2}a(x)v\; dx$ by the integral $\int_{\partial \Omega}a(x)v\; dx$ because $v\in H$, then use the continuity of the trace operator $\tau:H^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$

Comment: So are you saying that we can just apply the trace theorem even though $H$ only specifies the value of $v$ on $\partial \Omega_2$?

Comment: Yes. You don't need the information about the space $H$ for this step. You only need the information of $H$ for rewrite the integral as I said above. Then you can freely use the trace theorem to get the desired bound, because the function $v$ belongs to $H$ and therefore to $H^1$.